# Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x8e020c98

Tags: android

06-05 05:11:15.220078  3155  3155 I AEE/AED : Revision: '0'

06-05 05:11:15.220131  3155  3155 I AEE/AED : ABI: 'arm'

06-05 05:11:15.220477  3155  3155 I AEE/AED : pid: 3080, tid: 3080, name:

droid.apps.maps  >>> com.google.android.apps.maps <<<

06-05 05:11:15.220619  3155  3155 I AEE/AED : signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 
(BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 0x8e020c98

06-05 05:11:15.220766  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     r0 8e020c9d  r1 8e020c9c  r2 6867fe9d  r3 00000005

06-05 05:11:15.220841  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     r4 7d933648  r5 bec9075c  r6 00000005  r7 bec90834

06-05 05:11:15.220893  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     r8 a67e9140  r9 bec907c0  sl bec907a8  fp a67e9140

06-05 05:11:15.220943  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     ip fffffff7  sp bec90730  lr a637ac71  pc a65598c8  cpsr a00d0030

06-05 05:11:15.253080  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :

06-05 05:11:15.253080  3155  3155 I AEE/AED : backtrace:

06-05 05:11:15.253232  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #00 pc 002c78c8  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art7OatFile9OatMethod10LinkMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodE+39)

06-05 05:11:15.253324  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #01 pc 000e8c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker8LinkCodeEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7OatFile8OatClassEj+64)

06-05 05:11:15.253442  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #02 pc 000e9323  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker16LoadClassMembersEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_7DexFileEPKhNS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEPKNS_7OatFile8OatClassE+798)

06-05 05:11:15.253591  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #03 pc 000e67cb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9LoadClassEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_7DexFileERKNS3_8ClassDefENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEE+146)

06-05 05:11:15.253679  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #04 pc 000e42af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+338)

06-05 05:11:15.253790  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #05 pc 000e3fed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1008)

06-05 05:11:15.253892  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #06 pc 000e4bc3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+658)

06-05 05:11:15.253967  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #07 pc 000d2351  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+132)

06-05 05:11:15.254047  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #08 pc 000b0d93  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeEtPNS_9ArtMethodE+198)

06-05 05:11:15.254127  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #09 pc 001e9b01  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22ResolveVerifyAndClinitEjPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEbb+40)

06-05 05:11:15.254195  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #10 pc 003e8719  /system/lib/libart.so (artInitializeTypeFromCode+32)

06-05 05:11:15.254267  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #11 pc 000a995d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_initialize_type+28)

06-05 05:11:15.254334  3155  3155 I AEE/AED :     #12 pc 03968b7b  /system/app/Maps/oat/arm/Maps.odex (offset 0x393e000)

06-05 05:13:39.297847  3455  3455 F libc    : Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x8e020c98 in tid 3455 (droid.apps.maps)

Comment: Nice! What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have issue in `ndk` file of `arm` architecture , can you try to get logs of ndk stack using following command

```
adb logcat | /Users/userName/Library/Android/ndk/ndk-stack -sym <PATH-TO-ARM-SO-FILE>
```